# Ruby reflection question

Tags: ruby, class

I am new to Ruby so forgive me if the question is inconsistent. Can I iterate over class members like through array in Ruby? How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a class variable (array) and in constructor (`initialize`) push new instance into it.

```
class Foo
  @@instances = []

  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize name
    @name = name
    @@instances << self
  end

  def self.instances
    @@instances
  end

end

Foo.new("test")
Foo.new("test2")

Foo.instances.each do |i|
  puts i.name
end
```

Comment: I've always wondered this, so whether or not it's what the OP was asking (which I think it was), I am very thankful for your example.

Answer (score 6):

I think the OP might have been asking about whether you can get access to private, class, and instance variables.

Try this out in irb or some program:

`p YourClass.methods.sort`

In there you should see a bunch of methods that end in _methods or _variables. Each of these has the each method so you can easily do something like this:

```
YourClass.instance_variables.each do |x|
  p x
end
```

Answer (score 6):

What exactly do you mean with *class members*?

If you mean instance variables, you can get the via `instance.instance_variables`. If class variables, similarly with `klass.class_variables`.

If you want to get all variables and methods, you call additionally `instance.methods` (which actually return strings, and gets trickier because of the aliased methods, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

You can get a list of all constants defined in a module using `Module#constants`. Example:

```
Object.constants.sort
# => [:ARGF, :ARGV, :ArgumentError, :Array, :BasicObject, :Bignum, ... ]
```

For methods, you can call one of the various `Module#methods` methods:

```
Object.methods.sort
# =>  [:!, :!=, :!~, :<, :<=, :<=>, :==, :===, :=~, :>, :>=, :__id__, ... ]
```

You can get a list of all the various `methods` methods using reflection itself (yay meta):

```
Module.methods.sort.grep /methods/
# => [:instance_methods, :methods, :private_instance_methods, :private_methods, 
# =>  :protected_instance_methods, :protected_methods, :public_instance_methods, 
# =>  :public_methods, :singleton_methods]
```

It is impossible to get a list of the instance variables from a module for the simple reason that modules don't *know* about the instance variables, since unlike Smalltalk or Java, the instance variables aren't fixed by the class, they are simply dynamically added to the object as needed.